# calling a function again in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>input number</title>
</head>
<body>

enter no:1<input id="t1" type="text"><br>

<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">submit</button>
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">next</button>

<div id="div1" style="color:#0000FF">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(){

var no=document.getElementById("t1").value;

if(no==""||isNaN(no))
{
    alert("Not Numeric");
}

else{

    if(no!=1){

        if(no%2==0){

        no=no/2;
    }
    if (no%2!=0) {

        no=(no*3)+1;
    }
}
}


document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = no;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After entering number in the text box when I press submit button it shows the following output

enter no:1
submit next
16

but when i press next button it is not showing any output.My expected output is when I press next button it shoult show the next no. by executing the logic in the myFunction() function.Helpme...

Comment: I didn't understand the question :( Can you clarify more? When I give 5 as input and click submit button, the output is 16. What should be the output when you click next?

Comment: The value of the input field doesn't change, so why should the function give any other result?

Comment: why should next do anything different from submit?  It calls the same function

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set any case for when no = 1. You have a case for when no != 1 and when no%2 != 0 both of which are false when no = 1. There isn't any increment logic in here to find the next number and return it. I think you are missing a } at the end of the `no%2==0` clause.

Also I fail to see why you have two identical buttons here, next and submit do the same thing. Moreover I would advice more descriptive IDs. div1 isn't a good name for a div.

Comment: Yeah but 1 mod 2 is inside the no != 1 if statement, which come to think of it raises the point that he could fix it by adding a }

Comment: When input is 1, it will just set 1 to the output div. Maybe that is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript part should look like this, if the intention is to implement Collatz conjecture. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

```
function myFunction(){
    var no=document.getElementById("t1").value;

    if(no==""||isNaN(no)) {
        alert("Not Numeric");
    } else {
        if(no!=1) {
            if(no%2==0) {
                no=no/2;      // Note the division operator instead of mod
            } else {
                no=(no*3)+1;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("t1").value = no; // Note that we are writing to the textbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic HTML issues too, in your post you are using the input tag as

`<input id="t1" type="text">` use it as: `<input id="t1" type="text" />`

Secondly, when you submit the data to the function, you are having some value there! Maybe 1 is the value or 16, whatever. But when you are trying to resubmit, either its not allowed or your input is now an empty field. So the function is not executing further than this step:

`if(no==""||isNaN(no))`

Try to save the value in the form.

Try using this:

`document.getElementById("t1").value = no;`

Make sure that the value is captured as it was, because your code is changing the value into some other form, use a new variable for this. That would save the value from the input and again write it back to that input.

This will set the value for that text input as it was before the function. It might make the input again ready for the submit!